# Can $(x+5)^{2n} + 50 = (x+20)^n+100$ be simplified algebraically to give a solution?

Tags: logarithms

I have a brainteaser book which I'm working through and going overboard on. One puzzle is as follows:
Your boss offers you a choice of two bonuses (1) fifty dollars after six months and an ongoing semiannual increase of five dollars; or (2) one hundred dollars after a year and an ongoing annual increase of twenty dollars. Which bonus will prove more lucrative?
Rather than writing out a table, I wanted to calculate at what time one or the other becomes more lucrative.

I wrote out:
$$(x+5)^{2n} + 50 = (x+20)^n+100$$, where $n =$ number of years (assuming $n\ge1$)

Then tried taking the log of both sides, but end up with:
$$2n\log(x+5) = \log[(x+5)^n + 50]$$

How would I proceed from here, or must it be solved empirically?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An easy way out is first just write out what happens in the first 3 years. You will automatically get the answer and the general solution

Comment: The social solution (as opposed to the mathematical one) is that the first offer is better.  The second sounds better, so if the question is asked the answer is the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not written the correct equation.  You are using $x$ for your current salary, but you can ignore that.  The increases are additive, so you shouldn't be raising to the power $n$.  The first option gives you $45+5n$ in the $n^{\text{th}}$ half-year.  After $m$ years, you have received $\sum_{i=1}^{2m}45+5i$ dollars in bonus. The second gives you $80+20m$ in the $m^{\text{th}}$ year.  After $m$ years you have received $\sum_{i=1}^m80+20i$ dollars in bonus.  Sum those and you have an analytic solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if taking logs will get you anywhere, have you tried writing $$(x+5)^{2n}=5^{2n}\left(1+\frac{x}{5}\right)^{2n}=5^{2n}\left(1+2n\frac{x}{5}+n(2n-1)\frac{x^2}{25}+.....\right)$$ and then the same for the $$(x+20)^{n}$$ and comparing the infinite sums as $n$ gets large.